# How can CRUD using wpf form to sql databse?

Tags: c#, sql

How to resolve : insert error column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition?
I have attempted to use the same data type used in the SQL database however when I run my program in visual studio C# I couldn't get the desired outcome I want

Comment: You will have to provide the table definition and the code including the Insert command to get help.

Comment: private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LAPTOP-RH3HV5RF; Initial catalog = Formapp ; Integrated security =True") ;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Formtesting values (@Destination) ", cs);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Destination", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtdestination.Text;
            cs.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            cs.Close();
          
        }

Comment: code for the button function, error occurs at the da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery line

Comment: SQL table : column name -Destination : Data Type -VarChar(50): Allow null - checked

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the columns name you want to insert ("insert into yourTable (col1, col2) values (@para1, @para2);")
Also, I have never seem a paraneter being added like that. If the above doesn't work, try using Parameters.AddWithValue().

When dealing with connections, use:

```
using (var con = /*Connection declaration*/) {
   con.Open();
  // use connection here
}
```

This is important because, if you command fail, the connection will not be closed, meaning that soon, you server will be full of dead connections.